# how to adjust image saturation in YUV color space

Tags: image-processing, yuv

I want to know how to adjust image saturation in `YUV` color space, specially, the `U` component and the `V` component?

Comment: clam the values to 255... Can you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 8):

you probably want to scale the U and V components (using a center point of 128)

ex:

U = (U - 128) * Scale_factor) + 128;

V = (V - 128) * Scale_factor) + 128;

(and remember to clamp the values back to a valid range)

Comment: And use the same scale factor for both U and V.

Comment: it is maybe useful, I would be try to it, thank you for you answers！

Answer (score 2):

Even if is a old question This can be useful for people seeking an answer.
First of all the YUV  term must be used for the analog signal, for digital representation we must use the term YCbCr. Even if in the common language we use both interchangeably, the usage of the wrong terminology on a technical question can be misleading.

You can easily adjust the color saturation of a YCbCr image, without affecting its luminance, using the following formula:

```
Cb'= (Cb - 128) * saturation) + 128
Cr'= (Cr - 128) * saturation) + 128
```

However, often two other methods are used to adjust saturation:

- Multiply CbCr values to decrease saturation,
- Apply gamma to CbCr to increase saturation.

More information :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/adjusting_saturation_and_applying_tone_mapping

Further reading:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261500442_Saturation_adjustment_method_based_on_human_vision_with_YCbCr_color_model_characteristics_and_luminance_changes