# Change brightness of video using avconv

Tags: brightness, avconv

In contrast to ffmpeg, it does not seem to be possible to adjust brightness or other "quick" settings of videos anymore using avconv, at least a grep in the manpage for brightness did not give a single result. Gamma correction seems to be hidden in some kind of LUT-filter.

Can anyone point me to some option (in ffmpeg, those where mp,eq2,later eq) that allows me to do so?
(On a sidenote, can anyone explain why this fundamental and useful functionality has been stripped or obfuscated to the user?)

Comment: btw, just to let you know, you may also get answers to such questions on video.se

Answer (score 2):

Indeed as indicated in https://www.libav.org/avconv.html#lut_002c-lutrgb_002c-lutyuv you can use the following filters to change the gamma (use it with `-vf`):

```
lutyuv=y=gammaval(0.5)
```

or:

```
lutyuv="y=2*val"
```

If you are willing to play with RGB or YUV values you can probably get something better using formulas as in the examples of that website. For example, to increase saturation based on the formulas in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8810735/6040014:

```
lutyuv="y=2*val:u=(val-128)*2+128:v=(val-128)*2+128"
```

And an experiment with `y=(val-128)*2+128` seems to get a contrast increase (but maybe "contrast" is a technical term that should follow better formulas than this).