# Adjusting saturation after brightness correction in YUV space

Tags: image-processing, yuv

I am adjusting the brightness of a video in YUV space. I adjust the brightness using a gamma lookup table in the Y channel, but I make no changes to the U and V channels. Now the corrected image appears bright as we expect, whereas it looks under-saturated. An [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8810735/15198456) suggested a formula to fix the saturation. While, this would work with a constant scaling factor, how could this be accommodated to be used with a gamma curve. I did something like this:

```
U[idx] = ((U[idx] - 128) * GAMMA_CURVE[idx]) + 128
```

Rather than using the constant scaling factor from the former solution, I tried to extract the UV curves, using the gamma curve I had used earlier.

The image, now seems to be saturated, but I am not sure if this approach is correct.

Comment: "seems to be saturated" ? Do you mean that it *pretends* to be saturated ?

Comment: Well, sort of yes. But I find it a bit more _colorful_ than what I intend it to be.

Comment: Reduce the Gamma.

Comment: Ok, let me give that a try. Is there any form of correlation between a given Y value at the UV plane?

Comment: "correlation between a given Y value at the UV plane": what ?